How to translate the standard Power BI Filters panel into DAX format?
I would use the standard Power BI filter panel but the two filters I would like to use won't filter together so I'd like to do it in a DAX format instead.
I would like to have the filter act upon the Reference ID column to only show bookings that occurred on a Tuesday by employee 'Claire'.
I don't want to create a new table, I just want the current table I have filtered just on the Reference ID column.
This is the code I trialled first:
CALCULATE(
    [Reference ID],
    'Bookings'[Day Week] = "Tuesday",
    'Sales'[Employees] = "Claire"
)

I was expecting all the reference IDs that were booked on a Tuesday by Claire to show but I just get an error. I think it's because you can't use CALCULATE on a text string.
Does anyone know of an alternative filtering syntax to use instead?

I assume your question is: How can I use DAX to filter a Power BI table visual to display only the Reference IDs for bookings made on a Tuesday by an employee named Claire?
Your question is quite unclear:

'The two filters I would like to use won't filter together': What do you mean with this? Filters always filter together (AND operator). If they won't filter together, it means there is no relationship between your tables.
'The current table I have filtered': Be more specific. Is this the 'table visual' that you created, or the actual table that is loaded inside Power BI? You can always filter a table visual, but the actual table that is loaded inside Power BI will only be filtered during calculations.
What is exactly [Reference Id]? Is it a measure you created upfront, or a reference to a column in your table?

Without knowing your data model (the collection of tables and relationships in your Power BI file), it is difficult to answer your question accurately. However, here are some general guidelines:

The CALCULATE function changes the 'filter context' of an expression in which your table visual is working.
Assuming you have a table with solely the column 'Reference Id', that showcases all the Reference Ids, each 'cell' in your table has a specific filter context. As you can see in the image below, you basically apply a specific 'expression' (a count, sum, average, ...) for that specific filter context. You can compare it as if Power BI filters your whole data model with only that specific filter, and then gives you the result that you want. I also have another image of a table visual where it's more clear. 'Total references' is basically the count of all reference ids for a particular filter context, or in this case for each row (An, Bob, Claire), it filters the model for that employee, counts the total reference ids, and returns it.
The expression should be an expression that returns a scalar value, like a SUM, COUNT, etc. Just referencing a column will not return a list of all reference ids for something (which is a table).

Filter Context example #1
Filter Context example #2
The only way to achieve what you want is to use a slicer or the filter panel. However, without knowing your sample data and your Power BI model, I cannot answer the question fully.
